# MySQL Maximum number of fields theoretical vs practical

Tags: mysql

I have a table that currently has an id then 60 TINYINT(1) fields acting as booleans. I also need to add a complementary field to each of these for notes. The total number of fields would be around 120 then and I am wondering if any with experience of large tables could give any practical advice as I know I "can" create this, but what would the operational effects be and would they be noticeable?

Hardly any of the notes in one row would contain data. Maybe 4 to 5 at a time.

Any advice appricated

Comment: What datatype would `notes` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is a note?  25, 255, 1000 chars?

*Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of
65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this
limit, reducing the effective maximum row size.*

[Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html)

With varchar(255) UTF-8 you can have 85 columns, but with 1000 chars per column you are limited to 21.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  I would be interested in the thought behind it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to determine the impact is testing it. But I would normalize the table. Let's say the the table with 60 boolean fields is called "product" and the boolean fields are status fields. There are currently 60 status_options and we need a M:N table (many to many)

```
product
--------
id
name

status_option
--------------
id
name

product_status
---------------
id (not necessary if you combine product_id and status_option_id as primary key)
product_id
status_option_id
value (tinyint(1))
```